# Hide a div from a particular page and single pages in Wordpress

Tags: php

I am creating a wordpress theme from scratch. I have created a seperate page to show the Blog Posts. In my all pages I want to show a div class named as shopping-cart, but I want to hide it from page **id=42 (wordpress-naked BlogPage)** and **single.php**.

I have coded in my header.php like below

```
<?php if( is_page() ) { ?>

            <div  class="shopping-cart pull-right info" >Shopping Cart : <span class="simpleCart_quantity"></span> items - <span class="simpleCart_total"></span>
   <span class="ViewCART" onClick="myFunction()">View Cart</span>
 </div><!-----/.shopping-cart------------------------->

 <div class="down">
       <div class="triangle">&#x25B2;</div>

               <div ><h2>Your Cart Details</h2></div>
            <div class="cartData clearfix"><div class="left"><strong>Items: </strong><span class="simpleCart_quantity"></span></div>


                        <div class="right"><strong>Total: </strong><span class="simpleCart_total"></span></div></div>

            <div class="grandTotal"><strong>Grand Total:<div class="simpleCart_grandTotal"></div></strong></div>


           <div class="centercart"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_checkout" ><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/paypal.png"/></a></div>

            <div class="centercart"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_checkout" ><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/google-chk.png"/></a></div>
           <div class="centercart"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_empty"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/clear.png"/></a></div>
             <div class="closecart"><span onClick="myFunction2()">Close</span></div>
            </div><!-----/.down------------->


<?php } ?>
```

It is working fine. The particular div shopping-cart is showing in the pages and hiding from the single.php. But the problem is that I have coded Blog as a separate blog.php which is a page named as wordpress-naked BlogPage and having it's page id =42. 
So now I want to hide the shopping-cart div in the wordpress-naked BlogPage and single.php together.

I got stuck in this.
Can anyone please to sort it out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this:

```
<?php if( is_page() ) { ?>
```

to:

```
<?php if( is_page() && !is_page(42) ) { ?>
```

You can also try to use [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) and [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page). These 2 will be even better, since they are more universal (not based on pageId). If you change the page that is your home/front page, this will still work.

Comment: Thanks Drozdz. I was really stuck off in this. Thanks a lot again for your effort.. It worked...

Answer (score 0):

$page = get_query_var('page_id');

if($page == 42 || is_single() ) {

```
$class= 'shopping-yourname';
```

} else {

```
$class = 'shopping-cart';
```

}

Comment: Well, I don't think you should do this like that. You should use `is_page` and `is_single` functions...

Comment: Yes, and that's why is_page function have parameter ;)

Comment: The other problem with your answer is that all it does, is setting some `class` variable. So it isn't an answer at all, I guess.